# Does $y'''+\sqrt{x-1} y' +\ln(\sin x)y = \frac{\cos x}{x-3}$ have solution with these initial conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

First list of conditions:

$y(\pi/2)=1$

$y'(\pi/2)=0$

$y''(\pi/2)=1$

Second list:

$y'(\pi/2)=0$

$y''(\pi/2)=1$

$y'''(\pi/2)=1$

For each list, if there is solution, determine if it's unique.

I don't know how to solve the ODE and looks like calculators don't solve it, so I should use the existence and uniqueness theorem for linear ODE.

The functions $\sqrt{x-1}$ , $ln(sin x)$ and $\frac{cosx}{x-3}$ are continuous for some neighbourhood of $x=\pi/2$ so by the theorem we get that there is a unique solution for the problem.

But I don't see how that makes sense, I can say the same for the list:

$y(\pi/2)=x$

$y'(\pi/2)=y$

$y''(\pi/2)=z$

For any 3 numbers, because the existence and uniqueness theorem doesn't have anything to do with the value at the points (or perhaps I am wrong here)

This also doesn't go well with the third question - prove there are 3 linearly independent solutions, all have the point $(7,5)$